# Socket.io client side emits too many times to server side

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Please help me figure out why my socket.io app fires too many emit messages.

Yes, I have spent weeks on the socket.io docs and relevant stackO questions, experimented with the nesting of my functions and everything but I am just totally stuck.

This is supposed to allow people in a 'room' to vote on an issue.  Each client gets one vote (yea, nay, or abstain). The problem is when someone votes, it cannot just add one vote it adds a vote for the number of people in the socket. For example, if three people are in a room and the first vote is cast for 'yea' it registers 3x  'yea' votes. I cant get a good count ever!

client site:

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
const url      = window.location.href; 
let voteName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
let notVoted = true;

$('.voteName').html(voteName.replace(/_/g, ' '));

function getRoom(){
   return voteName;
}

socket.on('connect', () => {
   // Connected, let's sign-up for to receive messages for this room
 
   socket.emit('room', getRoom());
   console.dir(socket.id);
});

function yea () {
    if(notVoted){
        socket.emit('yea',voteName);
        console.log(voteName)
        notVoted = false;
    }
}

function nay () {
    if(notVoted){
        io.emit('nay',voteName);
        notVoted = false;
    }
}

function abs () {
    if(notVoted){
        io.emit('abs',voteName);
        notVoted = false;
    }
}
```

Server  Side:

```js
app.post('/votePick', (req, res) => { 
    let voteName = req.body.votePick;
    res.send(voteName);

    app.get('/'+voteName,(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/canvas.html');
    });
    
    var nsp = io.of('/');


    io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {

        socket.on('room', (voteName) => {

            //TODO check if room exists
            socket.join(voteName);

            if(!db[voteName]) {
                db[voteName]={'yea':0,'nay':0,'abs':0,'cnctCount':1};
                io.emit('update',db[voteName]);
           
            } else {
                io.emit('update',db[voteName]);
            }
        }); 

        socket.on('yea', (voteName)=>{
            db[voteName].yea++;
            io.emit('update',db[voteName]);
            console.log(db[voteName].cnctCount);
        });
        
        socket.on('nay', (voteName)=>{
            db[voteName].nay++;
            io.emit('update',db[voteName]);   
            console.log(db[voteName]);
        });
        
        socket.on('abs', (voteName)=>{
            db[voteName].abs++;
            io.emit('update',db[voteName]);   
            console.log(db[voteName]);
        });
    });
});
```

my full repo is here:
https://github.com/Bokeefe/sockerPractice

Comment: Should `socket.emit('room', getRoom());` be `socket.emit('room', getRoom);`?

Comment: That just returns the room name, grabbed from the URL, it needs to run the function to get the relevant room.

Answer (score 0):

You should do user validation. No one can prevent code on the clientside to be changed, so you always need to check on the serverside. For example you could store the socket ids that have already voted:

```
const voted = new Set;
```

then inside the socket event handlers:

```
if(voted.has(socket)) return;

voted.add(socket);

//vote
```

this should also solve the problem od votes counted twice.

Comment: Thank you! I'll need to stew on this a bit more to fully understand. I didn't really come across validation like this in the docs but it works.